# Create column from another dataframe, using existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns "Quantity" and "Unit", e.g.:

```
    Quantity    Unit
0   Current     A
1   Current     mA
2   Voltage     V
3   Length      m
4   Length      km
```

and I have a pandas DataFrame with ratios of units, e.g.:

```
      Current  Voltage  Length           
A       1        NaN      NaN
mA     1000      NaN      NaN
V      NaN       1        NaN
m      NaN       NaN      1000
km     NaN       NaN       1
```

Is it possible to create in first dataframe column with values of ratios?:

```
    Quantity    Unit   Ratio
0   Current     A        1
1   Current     mA      1000
2   Voltage     V        1
3   Length      m        1
4   Length      km      1000
```

I have tried to get every value by iterrows, but I have really big dataframe and it's not working correctly in case of time.
Maybe there is another, more expedient way to solve my issue, but I have to work with dataframes of ratios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas' `merge()` efficiently works as mapping data from one df to another

```py
# stack the second df and merge it with the first on Unit and Quantity
df1.merge(df2.stack().rename('Ratio'), left_on=['Unit', 'Quantity'], right_index=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `to_dict`:

```
d = df2.to_dict('i')

df['Ratio'] = df.apply(lambda s: d[s['Unit']][s['Quantity']], axis=1)
```

---

```
  Quantity Unit   Ratio
0  Current    A     1.0
1  Current   mA  1000.0
2  Voltage    V     1.0
3   Length    m  1000.0
4   Length   km     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the input dataframe

```
df
      Current  Voltage  Length           
A       1        NaN      NaN
mA     1000      NaN      NaN
V      NaN       1        NaN
m      NaN       NaN      1000
km     NaN       NaN       1
```

Then it seems like you want something as simple as

```
df.stack()

A   Current       1.0
mA  Current    1000.0
V   Voltage       1.0
m   Length     1000.0
km  Length        1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```py
df.assign(Ratio = df.Unit.map(ratios.bfill(axis = 1).Current))

  Quantity Unit   Ratio
0  Current    A     1.0
1  Current   mA  1000.0
2  Voltage    V     1.0
3   Length    m  1000.0
4   Length   km     1.0
```